# How to change the default styles of a documnt (the 'namedStyleType' values) during creation?

Tags: google-docs-api

I want to customize the `TITLE`, `SUBTITLE`, `NORMAL_TEXT`, `HEADING_1`, ... styles when creating a document. I tried adding a `namedStyle` property when calling `.create()` like so:

```js
gapi.client.docs.documents.create({
  title: "title",
  namedStyles: {
    styles: [
      {
        namedStyleType: "NORMAL_TEXT",
        textStyle: {...},
        paragraphStyle: {...},
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

but it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The namedStyles parameters is actually Output only:

> object (NamedStyles)
>
> Output only. The named styles of the document.

### Reference

[Documents API create method](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's not possible to add NamedStyles on Document creation.